# Extracting data from very large Oracle database which has blob column in everyrow

Tags: java, oracle, multithreading, jdbc

I am trying extract data from Oracle database which has 173 million rows and 40 different columns and each row has one blob column which has size of 30-50kb.

I am trying to extract data this data base using Java, the input file have 3 million rows, for every row we need modify the SQl statement according to that row and hit the database, we are going to make 3million different queries.

I am using executorServices for multiple threading in Java and I have tried Apache Commons DBCP2 and also c3p0 for connection pooling in java.

The normal wait to execute one query is 3 seconds even though I had indexes for columns that I am using in the database.

If i try to increase the threads in database the wait time is increasing.

| Threads | wait time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 50 | 5.5 |
| 100 | 10 |

I am able to see the improvement in the speed but it very low.

Please some one help me with this problem.

I am expecting better download speed and aby suggestions to improve the speed of fetching results.

Comment: I was extracting data from one table only which has 173 million rows

Comment: Why do you have to modify the query for every row? How are you measuring wait time? And how have you determined that the BLOB column is the problem? Including code for a [mre] might be helpful, but you also need to look at DB and maybe network settings etc.

Comment: At a minimum you will need to provide the SQL you are using so we see how you are distributing the data, and include an execution plan.

Comment: So you have a file with "something", and you want to extract data based on this file? Does the file contains IDs and such? I think 3 million queries sounds insane. Why not import the file into the database and use something called a JOIN to umm... join your imported data with the existing one and fetch whatever you need. You can still batch it up if memory etc is a problem but you definitely don't need 3 mils queries to fetch it all.